# Web service integration with iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services

I want to create iphone native app. which will use web service.Could any one tell me how many languages is supported by apple for web service. And which the best in performance ??

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "how many languages is supported by apple for web service"?

Comment: Php ?? java? .net or ruby this all are supported by apple??? If yes then which is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service implementation is completely independent from your iPhone native app. Apple does not care what language you implement your web service in.

However, your web service client (i.e.: your iPhone app) must be written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Object Access Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is a webservice multi-platform language, and its the default for web services.

In a [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) these problems are addressed. Because the need to communicate with services that are not in the same programming language is something that happens normally. And there appears the SOAP protocol to normalize it.

This is independent from your iPhone.